# Jwplayer 6.11 HLS play unexpectedly

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am trying to upgrade jwplayer to latest version 6.11 because seek event in this version works properly. However hls video is not playing properly. Here I have different urls for 6.10 and 6.11

6.10 at https://vplayer.mindtickle.com/a.php
6.11 at https://vplayer.mindtickle.com/b.php

Video is only 2.08 long but in 6.11 it shows 3:20:58 and after few seconds stops playing. sometimes no video as well. Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That is very weird. Something seems wrong with your stream, it won't even play in VLC properly. https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mtgame-cdn.mindtickle.com/test1/1418289402931AllAboardMindTickle.mp4/hls/playlist.m3u8

Comment: was playing fine in jwplayer 6.8, 6.9 so I thought if any issue with player or my setup. Thanks I will try other streams

Comment: Np. I would try the other streams. As you can see, it doesn't even load in VLC at all.

Comment: Yes it does not load in VLC but then my question was why it was working in jwplayer 6.10 then suddenly stopped in 6.11 as you can see in the example. I have reached JWplayer support then they said it is bug and escalated to engg team. Thanks!

Comment: Who from our team did you speak with?

Comment: I got response from Todd

Comment: Thanks, I will follow up with him.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** New release 6.12 has fixed bug about unexpected stop with long-duration file

I've checked a very big problem with 6.11 and long duration hls stream. 
We can't play after 3 hours and 30 minutes (with 4 or 5 hours file), because the player stop playing and go to next file in playlist or go back to the start. 
We've checked this problem with mp4, m4a, mp3 and f4v file format, so the problem there's for all hls stream with flash player. 
Trying with previous version like 6.10 we haven't problem and all stream play fine until the end.

**Workaround:** until this bug is fixed you can use previuos jwplayer version like 6.10 or 6.9 that works good

Comment: new jwplayer 6.12 has fixed this bug!